# SQL Server Ubuntu 16.04 - “Nothing” works (It always hangs)

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server

**Note:**

I have asked this question on Database administrators previously, but I have deleted it over there because I think it suits better here. That's why this question already contains edits and I have coppied the comments from DBA to this question.

---

I have installed SQL Server 2017 (Express) on my clean(just reinstalled Ubuntu) Ubuntu 16.04 VPS. I followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017) tutorial for it.

After that I installed sqlcmd, first it just terminated, but I solved that problem by setting my locales right. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/163) GitHub thread.

I can connect to the server from the VPS. when issuing the command:

> sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P PASSWORD

I do get `1>` but when I type my query and type `GO` it just hangs.

Also when I issue my query directly with `-Q`. It just hangs everytime.

So, I decided to try it in SSMS. It does connect, but as soon it's connected SSMS just hangs (not responding).

I've been googling for a while now but didn't manage to find any solution. What could be the problem?

**EDIT 1:**

`top` when it hangs:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, this is really weird tbh. I have tried restarting the process, it hangs. Shutting it down, not possible. Killing the process, nope! So I tried rebooting the server. Now I can't even connect anymore... Might be time for another reinstall :(. I really don't understand this, at all...

**EDIT 3:**

Okay, 4 reinstalls further and it still does not work. I am a bit of a Linux noob, I know how to do basic stuff, but I just don't understand this at all. I feel like I've tried everything, but it just won't work. Clean Ubuntu install, following the tutorial like a dog and it just does not work. Please help.

**EDIT 4:**

One more thing I might need to point out is that my locale is set to NL_nl. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I do get the message that it's not supported.

**EDIT 5:**

Tested the above. Nope, not the problem. :(

---

**Comments from DBA:**

- Is Ubunto a supported OS? – Michael Kutz
- @MichaelKutz Yes, it is. See the first link. – Luuk Wuijster
- How long have you waited for it? – Max Vernon
- @MaxVernon A minute or 2-3 – Luuk Wuijster
- Can you run top when it hangs? Via ssh shell. – Max Vernon
- @MaxVernon I have added an image to my question – Luuk Wuijster
- I've added some extra info to my question. – Luuk Wuijster